# I need mma coomand to build avahi module want to include it into make command AOSP

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-source, mdns, avahi

I am using AOSP Nougat source code.
I want to build avahi module for my custom hardware to support mdns. I can build it using `mma` command.

I want to include this module in build when I use `make` command.

Can anyone suggest the way to do it.

Comment: Add it to the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` of your device. Grep `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` in this page https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device

Comment: Hi Hugo,The issue is that the binary file (at out/target/product/BOARD/system/bin )is not generated when I use make command. but Instead when I use mma( Build with dependency) command it is generated.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. Your avahi module have an Android.mk get the LOCAL_MODULE value and put it in the PRODUCT_PACKAGES variable of your device. Like this PRODUCT_PACKAGES += your_avahi_name .

Comment: @Hugoy is correct. And should make that an answer, not comment.

Comment: @Hugoy Please write this as an answer so that I can mark it as answered. Thanks

Comment: Ok, it's done .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your avahi module have an `Android.mk` get the `LOCAL_MODULE` value and put it in the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` variable of your device.

Like this `PRODUCT_PACKAGES += your_avahi_name` .

More info on `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` on [this page](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device) (search for `PRODUCT_PACKAGES`).